# I want ClassA to get particular a particular instance of ClassB, but can't modify either class directly

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, guice

Say I have two `JdbcTemplates`, one for "employee_database" and one for "customer_database".  Say a class `EmployeeDAO` requires the former as a constructor dependency, and `CustomerDAO` requires the latter.  If I were writing these classes myself, I'd do

```
public class EmployeeDAO {
  public EmployeeDAO(@Named("employee") JdbcTemplate employeeJdbcTemplate)
```

and

```
bind(JdbcTemplate.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("employee")).toInstance(employeeJdbcTemplateInstance);
```

And likewise for CustomerDAO

But I can't modify `EmployeeDAO` to add the `Named` annotation to the constructor parameters.

What's the canonical way to insure the DAO objects get their respective JdbcTemplates in this scenario without having to instantiate them myself?

Answer (score 3):

In a sense, this is similar to the ["robot legs problem"](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#how-do-i-build-two-similar-but-slightly-different-trees-of-objects), as you're trying to create similar-but-slightly-different trees of objects. In the eponymous problem, you're using a reusable Leg object that receives a @Left Foot and a @Right Foot as needed; in this problem, you're similarly varying the binding of an inner object (JdbcTemplate) based on an outer object's (DAO's) context.

A "cheap way" is to use [`@Provides` methods](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ProvidesMethods), which is a particularly low-cost solution if your consumer DAOs have few dependencies and are unlikely to change frequently. Naturally, creating a full Provider would also work too, but this syntax works just fine for most cases.

```
public class YourModule extends AbstractModule {
  @Override public void configure() {}

  @Provides EmployeeDao createEmployeeDao(  // Name doesn't matter.
      @Named("employeeJdbcTemplate") JdbcTemplate employeeTemplate,
      Dep2 dep2,
      Provider<Dep3> dep3Provider) {
    return new EmployeeDao(employeeTemplate, dep2, dep3Provider);
  }
}
```

If the dep list is long, deps change frequently, or multiple classes depend on a JdbcTemplate, then [private modules](http://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/PrivateModule.html) may be the way to go.

```
install(new PrivateModule() {
  @Override public void configure() {
    bind(JdbcTemplate.class).toInstance(employeeJdbcTemplate);
    expose(EmployeeDao.class);
  }
});
```

The example above uses an anonymous inner class, but you could also create a named class (either top-level or nested) that accepts a JdbcTemplate instance and a DAO class literal, and call it like so:

```
install(new DaoModule(employeeTemplate, EmployeeDao.class));
install(new DaoModule(customerTemplate, CustomerDao.class));
```